# Python 3.7.7 embed - Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-3.7, python-embedding

I work on a project and I need to install **python-3.7.7-embed-amd64**. I get it from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-377/

When I tried to run this commands, I received the following output:

```
> python --version
  Python 3.7.7

> python
  Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I found some solutions that assumed that maybe environment variables would not be set correctly.
But I think mine are set correctly.

```
> echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\ela\python-3.7.7-embed-amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;C:\Users\ela\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Users\ela\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\payara\tools\payara41\bin;C:\Users\ela\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ela\WildFly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin;C:\Users\ela\npm-global\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;C:\Users\ela\AppData\Local\atom\bin;
```

So, in path I have the correct path for Python: **C:\Users\ela\python-3.7.7-embed-amd64;**

What do you think I should try to get rid of this error?

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Comment: I have the same problem with Python embedded in a Cython-compiled executable. Did you end up figuring out what was the matter in your case?

Answer (score 0):

This error is very likely due to running the Windows `embed.zip` without the needed modifications.

The Windows Python `embed.zip` distribution requires some modifications; it does not run correctly "out of the box".

I created a PowerShell script, [`PythonEmbed4Win.ps1`](https://github.com/jtmoon79/PythonEmbed4Win), to install the `embed.zip` Python distribution downloaded from the Internet, and then modify the installation so it will run without errors.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jtmoon79/PythonEmbed4Win/main/PythonEmbed4Win.ps1" -OutFile "PythonEmbed4Win.ps1"

.\PythonEmbed4Win.ps1 -Version 3.7
```

> So, in path I have the correct path for Python: C:\Users\ela\python-3.7.7-embed-amd64;

Modifying `PATH` is only necessary if you want to type just "`python`" from your command shell. Otherwise, invoke `python` (`python.exe`) by it's full path, e.g. `C:\Users\ela\python-3.7.7-embed-amd64\python.exe` .